# How to pipe binary stdout to a compressed tls connection?

Tags: bash, shell-script, bash-scripting, pipe

Not so long ago, I could use :

```
cat somefile.txt | openssl s_client -connect server:port -quiet -comp
```

However, this command doesn’t work, even with`-ign_eof`:

```
$ cat somefile.bmp | openssl s_client -connect server:port -quiet -ign_eof
write:errno=32
```

because somefile consists of pure binary data *(where`.bmp`is the only format recognized by the server and`somefile.bmp`would takes too much time to be send uncompressed)*.

It’s not for security purposes, as the data I’m sending is public, however I don’t control the sever which disallow non secured connections.

Comment: In reality, somefile.bmp is dynamically generated by my bash script as several parts of the sending requires waiting the response from the server, so I can’t read from file directly, but need to use a pipe.

Comment: Your pipe is broken, that's what errno 32 means, so, I suggest you to use `enc base64`, before doing the cat

Comment: @MoisesNajar : ok your’re right http://stackoverflow.com/q/36924673/2284570

Answer (score 0):

If there is any line breaks(eg. `\n`) in your binary, you should add the flag `-crlf` to `openssl s_client` command to make it recognize the line breaks.

Comment: They are crlfs line breaks so this won’t works. I’m sending compressed data.

Answer (score -1):

`-comp` has been introduced in openssl 1.1.0

https://www.openssl.org/docs/manmaster/ssl/SSL_CONF_cmd.html

On cygwin openssl is 1.0.2g-3, so you can not use it. 
Can you try another image format ?

Comment: The problem isn’t with`-comp`whether the option is present or not it doesn’t work. **Please read the question body**.

Comment: May be you should not write misleading question. ` I could use` is not true on cygwin.

Comment: Compiling openssl is trivial if you have the required packages already installed. Just focus on the problem described in the question. I read an existing post on the openssl mailing list with the same problem, the developers replied that`s_client`is for testing purpose and not for something real, and that something like`stunnel`should be used instead *(which is the point of my post because I don’t see how stunnel can be use with a pipe)*